# In MUI v5 sx prop,Is there a performance difference between passing an object literal vs object reference?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

```
const anotherStyles = {p:2};

function Testing () => {
    return (
        <Literal sx={{p:2}} />
        <Reference sx={anotherStyles} />
        <Styled />
    );
}
```

Is there a performance difference between `<Literal />` and `<Reference />`?
(I'm assuming since `anotherStyle` reference stays same, it prevent re-renders).
I understand that `sx` is the least performant out of all options, but is there a difference if object reference is passed and how does it compare with a styled or emotion component?

Comment: Nice question! I was wondering the same. Creating the new object and pass that to sx, must come with some kind of cost.

Comment: I would remove everything from the question that isn't specifically about your question title. I'd move the styled/emotion bit to another question.